# uncheckbox when delete ngModel with Mat-select multiple angular5

Tags: angular, angular-material

My code is below:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select [formControl]="employeename" [(ngModel)]="selectedName" multiple (selectionChange)="selectedchange()" >
        <mat-select-trigger>
                    {{employeename.value ? employeename.value[0] : ''}}
                    <span *ngIf="employeename.value?.length > 1" >
                      (+{{employeename.value.length - 1}} {{employeename.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
                    </span>
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let employee of employeeNames " [value]="employee" data-ng-selected="true">{{employee}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

I've deleted a element of `selectedName: this.selectedName.splice(index, 1);`.

However, in `mat-select` multiple dropbox, the deleted element is uncheckbox .

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Angular's change detection compares by reference. When you splice the array, there's no way for the select to know that anything changed. You can work around it either by reassigning the array or setting the value through a FormControl, e.g.:

```
this.selectedName = this.selectedName.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: ohh. sorry it's wrong. selectedName will just be an element which is deleted by above way :)